# Changing Galleriffic controls

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the jQuery Galleriffic gallery and I am trying to do somthing that I am not sure is possible.

I want to take the buttons that changing the pictures and start the slide show and put them inside divs.

I was able to put all of them in a div out side the gallery but I can't find a way to put them separately inside divs.

Is it even possible to do that?
I looked in the javascript code and I found a code that change the pictures:

```
next: function(dontPause, bypassHistory) {
    this.gotoIndex(this.getNextIndex(this.currentImage.index), dontPause, bypassHistory);
    return this;
}
```

But when I try to use it outside the Galleriffic initialization the script breaks.
My javascript is not the best, is it possible to call that function?

Sorry for my english.

**EDIT:-----------------------------------------------------------------------------**

I found the solution after looking the Galleriffic source again and found the correct functions.

They called:

> gallery.next(); //for going foward.
>
> gallery.previous(); // for going backwards.

You can make a div style him the way you want and link this function to it with javascript (I use jQuery).

Here a simple example:

```
$("#foward").click(function () {
    gallery.next();
});

$("#backward").click(function () {
    gallery.previous();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#foward").click(function () {
    gallery.next();
});

$("#backward").click(function () {
    gallery.previous();
});
```